# React App: Tiny MCE do not highlight code after saving like i does while editing

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, editor

React App: Tiny MCE do not highlight code after saving like i does while editing

**Edit mode**
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sqkq7k?file=src/App.js)

[image]
**View Mode**
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aaupt1?file=src/App.js)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `codesample` plugin relies on a library called `Prism.js`. This is outlined here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/codesample/#usingprismjsonyourwebpage

You will need to implement Prism in your web page to get the same look as you see in TinyMCE.